# There is an unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

**display_art.php**

```
print"<td><a href='member.php?username=$username'>$username</td>";
```

**member.php:** *Code displays all artstyle done by one user. When trying to 
   connect it says Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'*

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","Artworks" ); 

 $results = mysqli_query($db, "select * from artwork where username = 
{$_GET['username']}")or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Table:

```
create table artwork(
    artwork_id serial primary key,
    username text,
    title text,
    category text,
    description text,
    tags text,
    filename text
    );
```

Comment: Is column username present in artwork table?

Comment: yes it is present in the table

Comment: Update your question and add  your table schema

Answer (score 0):

Be sure for correct case sensitive  matching column name and use a prepared  statement

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","Artworks" ); 

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "select * from artwork where username =  ?") or die(mysqli_error($db));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's',$_GET['username']);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

this way you should avoid quotes, and sqlinjection   issue